# Different behaviour of matplotlib in interpretor and in script

Tags: python, matplotlib

Running following code inside python interpretor displays a figure with random values

```
>>>fig = plt.figure();ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111);plt.ion();ax1 = ax1.imshow(np.random.rand(256,256))
```

while running the following script as a file does not display any output/figure.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.ion()
ax1 =ax1.imshow(np.random.rand(256,256))
```

what is the reason for difference in behaviour?

Comment: you need to add `plt.show()` in the script. Long answer short, it has to do with backends.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what is going on is that

```
matplotlib.rcParams['interactive'] == True
```

and this is set in your `.matplotlibrc` file.

which means that `plt.show` is non-blocking (so that you get a figure that you can interact with *and* an command prompt you can type more code at).  However, in the case of a script the (implicit) `plt.show` does not block so the script exits, taking the figure with it.

I suggest the setting the `interactive` rcparam to `False` and then either explitily setting it to true in the repl or (the preferred method) use `IPython` and the `%matplotlib` magic.